# How to 'un-cache' ajax-loaded html when user leaves page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Right now, when a user clicks on a link on my site, I use ajax to only replace the content in the main frame (the header and a sidebar need to keep state across pages, so I don't want to reload them).  I use pushState and popState to alter the url bar.

I explicitly do not cache the ajax content and my site works fine--but it's a bit too slow-feeling, particularly on 'back' commands.

If I do cache the xhr html requests, then the site works well internally. However, if a user enters a new URL and leaves the site, if he/she hits the 'back' command, only the unstyled, header and side-bar-less main view content will be pulled from the cache and the site won't display properly.

Is there any way for me to have caching internally but flush the cache if the user leaves the page?

Comment: Have you tried generating a unique ID on domready and using that same unique id for every request for the life of the document?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to detect when the user leaves the page.

Comment: Victor, there's `window.onbeforeunload` but from what I've heard you can only effectively stop a user with a pop-up message.  If I knew a way to clear the cache I could see if it acted in time before the user left.

Comment: Kevin, I'm not sure that would solve my problem. Are you talking about sticking the uniqueID in the URL? When the user pressed 'back' after having left my page, and if I let him cache the page with the uniqueID, his browser would still load the cached content without ever talking to my server.  Let me know if I'm missing your meaning.

Comment: In theory, I think I could stick a script tag inside each bit of body content and have it check for a dom element in the header.  If the element isn't there, I refresh the page.  This would solve the problem, but it seems like there must be a better way...

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would need to flush the cache. Can you link to a url?

Comment: I implemented my proposed theoretical fix, and it solved my original problem (and was less messy than I expected). Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that any caching is actually taking place even with cache set to 'on' on my intrapage requests.

Comment: To Sean, I'm trying to replicate what facebook in that it is able to both cache and serve the main page as normal yet maintain state of its sidebar by using some mixture of iframes and injected javascript.  I was hoping I could achieve similar performance (and functionality of the back/forward buttons) by just grabbing my page content with ajax, but it appears caching doesn't work effectively this way.

Comment: You need to have an account and be logged in for it to kick in, but you can have a look at http://www.dexy.tv

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your description now.

When I visit /page1.html on your site then the downloaded HTML has main content + header + sidebar. 
When I click a link to visit /page2.html, AJAX loads the page and the downloaded HTML has main content ONLY.

So, at this point the cache contains a full /page1.html and a partial /page2.html

Now, when I leave your site and then return with the back-button, the browser grabs /page2.html from cache. But that is only a partial page, and your site "breaks".

Ideally you want the browser to grab partial content only when requested with XMLHttpRequest. 
Also, it would be nice if both the partial and full pages could be cached.

[pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) addresses this issue by appending a `_pjax=true` param to the URL query in the AJAX request. I think this should just work in most scenarios.

NOTE that you don't add this param to the URL that you pass to `pushState()`.

An alternative to this would be to ALWAYS download the full page, and then extract the `#main-view` when using AJAX.

Of course, you could make this someone else's problem by switching to PJAX (you'll need to use the `fragment` option).

Another JS lib that handles pushState() for you is my [HTMLDecor](http://github.com/shogun70/HTMLDecor) project. With HTMLDecor, your pages only contain main content + a `<link>` to another (presumably shared) HTML page that contains the header / footer / sidebar. HTMLDecor adds these to the page from within the browser. When the user clicks on a link to browse to another page, HTMLDecor uses AJAX and pushState - no configuration needed. Of course, if the browser doesn't support pushState then a normal link navigation occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Sean. Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time implementing them effectively. The pjax demo doesn't seem to actually be doing what it says it does, even in the online demo, in Chrome at least. It just reloads the whole page each time. It may no longer work with the newest version of jquery. As for HTMLDecor, I'm getting an error about a missing DOM element in `document.head.insertBefore(script, style)` in the `hide` function even though I'm trying to replicate your set-up example. I'll keep playing with it and see if I can make it work, though. Your demo does work

Comment: @trespassers-w: The pjax [online demo](http://pjax.heroku.com/) requires a checkbox to be ticked for pushState to be enabled. If it still doesn't work after you do that, I'm sure the pjax devs would appreciate a bug report.

Comment: @trespassers-w: Thanks for the info RE: HTMLDecor. The error message indicates that the HTMLDecor script hasn't being included in the `<head>` of the page. This is a bad assumption in HTMLDecor which I shall address promptly. If you have more questions about HTMLDecor, please do so via the [project site](http://github.com/shogun70/HTMLDecor).

Comment: You're right about the pjax demo, it works now, and right again that I was including HTMLDecor in my footer with my other scripts.  Will fix that.